# reverse a string column in pandas dataframe in a speicifc order

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have this column in my dataframe, which is basically a date.

```
0       2023-01-01
1       2023-01-01
2       2023-01-01
3       2023-01-01
4       2023-01-01
           ...    
1015    2023-01-17
1016    2023-01-17
1017    2023-01-17
1018    2023-01-17
1019    2023-01-17
```

I want to convert the above column into

```
0       01-01-2023
1       01-01-2023
2       01-01-2023
3       01-01-2023
4       01-01-2023
           ...    
1015    17-01-2023
1016    17-01-2023
1017    17-01-2023
1018    17-01-2023
1019    17-01-2023
```

I tried to use this:

```
df['date'] = "-".join(reversed(df['date'].split("-")))
```

But I'm getting below error:

```
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'split'
```

Is there a better way to change this column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use lambda function:

```
df['date'] = df['date'].apply(lambda x: "-".join(reversed(x.split("-"))))
df['date'] = df['date'].str.split('-').apply(reversed).str.join('-')
```

Better solution is convert datetimes to custom strings:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date']).dt.strftime('%d-%m-%Y')
```

Answer (score 1):

We could use `str.replace` here for a regex option:

```py
df["date"] = df["date"].str.replace(r'(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})', r'\3-\2-\1', regex=True)
```

However, the "better" solution as given by @jezrael is to convert your text `date` column to a bona-fide date.  Then, if you want to *view* your dates in a certain format, use `strptime()`.